# Grouping into series based on days since

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-server-2008

I need to create a new grouping every time I have a period of more than 60 days since my previous record.

Basically, I need too take the data I have here:

```
RowNo   StartDate   StopDate    DaysBetween
1   3/21/2017   3/21/2017   14
2   4/4/2017    4/4/2017    14
3   4/18/2017   4/18/2017   14
4   6/23/2017   6/23/2017   66
5   7/5/2017    7/5/2017    12
6   7/19/2017   7/19/2017   14
7   9/27/2017   9/27/2017   70
8   10/24/2017  10/24/2017  27
9   10/31/2017  10/31/2017  7
10  11/14/2017  11/14/2017  14
```

And turn it into this:

```
RowNo   StartDate   StopDate    DaysBetween Series
1   3/21/2017   3/21/2017   14  1
2   4/4/2017    4/4/2017    14  1
3   4/18/2017   4/18/2017   14  1
4   6/23/2017   6/23/2017   66  2
5   7/5/2017    7/5/2017    12  2
6   7/19/2017   7/19/2017   14  2
7   9/27/2017   9/27/2017   70  3
8   10/24/2017  10/24/2017  27  3
9   10/31/2017  10/31/2017  7   3
10  11/14/2017  11/14/2017  14  3
```

Once I have that I'll group by Series and get the min(StartDate) and max(StopDate) for individual durations.

I could do this using a cursor but I'm sure someone much smarter than me has figured out a more elegant solution.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the window function `sum() over` with a conditional FLAG

**Example**

```
Select *
     ,Series= 1+sum(case when [DaysBetween]>60 then 1 else 0 end) over (Order by RowNo)
 From YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
RowNo   StartDate   StopDate    DaysBetween Series
1       2017-03-21  2017-03-21  14          1
2       2017-04-04  2017-04-04  14          1
3       2017-04-18  2017-04-18  14          1
4       2017-06-23  2017-06-23  66          2
5       2017-07-05  2017-07-05  12          2
6       2017-07-19  2017-07-19  14          2
7       2017-09-27  2017-09-27  70          3
8       2017-10-24  2017-10-24  27          3
9       2017-10-31  2017-10-31  7           3
10      2017-11-14  2017-11-14  14          3
```

**EDIT - 2008 Version**

```
Select A.*
      ,B.*
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
               Select Series=1+sum( case when [DaysBetween]>60 then 1 else 0 end) 
                From  YourTable
                Where RowNo <= A.RowNo
             ) B
```

Comment: . . This doesn't have XML.  You're  not supposed to answer it ;)

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm a man of many interests.  For example I write "My Little Pony" fan fiction  :)

Comment: Thank you, I've never used the OVER portion on SUM.  Makes sense but using your example SQL above I'm getting  an Incorrect syntax near 'order' Msg.  Should I be using a partition by clause?  I'm on MS SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: @WSaunders If the column "order" then you need to keep in mind that "ORDER" is a reserved word and must be treated as such [Order] ... with the brackets.   Now, on the other hand, the window function sum() over was introduced in 2012.  What version are you on?

Comment: MS SQL Server 2008 R2   :(

Comment: @WSaunders Give me a moment for a 2008 option

Comment: @WSaunders See EDIT 2008 Version

Comment: @WSaunders Just saying...  2008 Extended Supported ends July 2019.  Be sure to tag your SQL questions with 2008 to avoid assumptions.

Comment: @WSaunders Happy to help